# Pressing the Q key in any application in gnome-terminal quits terminal?

Tags: linux, keyboard, gnome-terminal

I recently set up Linux (Debian 6), and am running Openbox as my WM. My problem is that, whenever I press the <kbd>Q</kbd> key in the terminal, whether in a script, program, app or just typing a command, it kills the terminal.

What's wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Are you sure your Ctrl key is not stuck?

Comment: It isn't, since this has been going on for a few days now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have GNOME configured to dynamically rebind accelerators, and you pressed <kbd>Q</kbd> while you had the mouse over the `Close Window` menu item. Hover over the same item and press <kbd>Backspace</kbd> or another accelerator you'd rather assign to it.

Comment: Uh, how? Since wheen I try by right-clicking the title-bar, there is no option to edit keybindings.

Comment: Hover over the menu item and press the desired accelerator.

Comment: I mean, if I can't open the menu, my menu doesn't have any option to change profile or keyboard.

Comment: Nvm, I found it.